# I cannot index my database with solr. I always get `Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.`

Tags: mysql, docker, solr, solr4, dataimporthandler

I cannot index my mysql database with solr (4.0). I always get `Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.` I already review previous answers and I can't figure out what it's the problem. I am running it in a Docker (passenger phusion and ubuntu 14.04) container. Any ideas? I already spent a few days trying to figure out this.

DOCKER COMPOSE

```
version: '2'

services:
  search:
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
      # - ~/.solr:/data/solr/
      - ./docker:/home/app/docker
  db:
    env_file: .env
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

SOLR_HOME

```
ls -l /data/solr/collection1/conf/
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  7601 Oct 17 15:35 data-config.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7     0 Oct 17 15:35 dataimport.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   561 Oct 17 15:35 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   707 Oct 17 15:35 log4j.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7 12302 Oct 17 15:35 schema.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   479 Oct 17 15:35 solrconfig-qf.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7 41383 Oct 17 15:35 solrconfig.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   148 Oct 17 15:35 solrcore.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   138 Oct 17 15:35 solrcore.properties.template
```

Solr Admin

[image: Solr Admin]

data-config.xml https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce99aa9277f0295a2a52768fb7866e6a

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource name="db" type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datacite" user="root"
    password="" readonly="true"
    batchSize="-1" />
  <!-- for batchSize=-1 see DIH FAQ -->
  <dataSource name="field" type="FieldReaderDataSource" />
  <document>
    <!-- SOLR-2104 -->
    <!-- using delta import as proposed in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport -->
```

Sorl Core Properties

```
mds.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datacite?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8
mds.db.user=datacite
mds.db.password=
mds.testprefix=10.5072
```

Solrconfig.xml

```
<!-- AutoCommit

     Perform a hard commit automatically under certain conditions.
     Instead of enabling autoCommit, consider using "commitWithin"
     when adding documents.

     http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

     maxDocs - Maximum number of documents to add since the last
               commit before automatically triggering a new commit.

     maxTime - Maximum amount of time in ms that is allowed to pass
               since a document was added before automaticly
               triggering a new commit.
     openSearcher - if false, the commit causes recent index changes
     to be flushed to stable storage, but does not cause a new
     searcher to be opened to make those changes visible.
  -->
 <autoCommit>
   <maxTime>15000</maxTime>
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
 </autoCommit>

<!-- softAutoCommit is like autoCommit except it causes a
     'soft' commit which only ensures that changes are visible
     but does not ensure that data is synced to disk.  This is
     faster and more near-realtime friendly than a hard commit.
  -->
 <!--
   <autoSoftCommit>
     <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
   </autoSoftCommit>
  -->

<!-- Update Related Event Listeners

     Various IndexWriter related events can trigger Listeners to
     take actions.

     postCommit - fired after every commit or optimize command
     postOptimize - fired after every optimize command
  -->
<!-- The RunExecutableListener executes an external command from a
     hook such as postCommit or postOptimize.

     exe - the name of the executable to run
     dir - dir to use as the current working directory. (default=".")
     wait - the calling thread waits until the executable returns.
            (default="true")
     args - the arguments to pass to the program.  (default is none)
     env - environment variables to set.  (default is none)
  -->
<!-- This example shows how RunExecutableListener could be used
     with the script based replication...
     http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CollectionDistribution
  -->
<!--
   <listener event="postCommit" class="solr.RunExecutableListener">
     <str name="exe">solr/bin/snapshooter</str>
     <str name="dir">.</str>
     <bool name="wait">true</bool>
     <arr name="args"> <str>arg1</str> <str>arg2</str> </arr>
     <arr name="env"> <str>MYVAR=val1</str> </arr>
   </listener>
  -->

<!-- Enables a transaction log, currently used for real-time get.
     "dir" - the target directory for transaction logs, defaults to the
        solr data directory.  -->
<updateLog>
  <str name="dir">/data/solr/collection1/data</str>
</updateLog>
```

```
  <dataDir>/data/solr/collection1/data</dataDir>


  <lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="../../../lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" />

  <requestHandler name="/admin/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="db.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datacite?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF8</str>
      <str name="db.user">root</str>
      <str name="db.password"></str>
      <str name="testprefix">10.5072</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? 1. Logs (the entire error stacktrace, not just the error message). 2. Your SQL query 3. What steps are you following to import the data? 4. Does it fail immediately? 5. How many records are you expecting to import. Disable `autoSoftCommit` since its a bulk insert (right now its doing a softCommit every second).

Comment: Have a look at your physical memory, second screenshot of yours, the Solr Admin UI. The disk is nearly full.

Comment: @jay (1) Actually I have not been able to find more information about the error. The tomcat logs (catalina.) don't show anything wrong and the logs in the solr admin interface always appear empty just a spinning wheel. The message I mentioned is the only feedback I have got. Is there any place you suggest I could look into?  (3) Sorry, I am not sure what you mean on this question? (4) It fails everytime I run solr `full import`. it indexes nothing, the index is empty. (5) 1000s the mysql database size is 500Mb. thanks

Comment: @jay (2) the full [data-config.xml ](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce99aa9277f0295a2a52768fb7866e6a)

Comment: Does mysql actually run inside the same docker container as your Solr installation? 127.0.0.1 might not be the ip of your actual MySQL server. Can you connect to MySQL from the command line _on the docker instance Solr lives in_ and issue queries with the details provided? (and Solr 4.0 is getting really old)

Comment: @MatsLindh (1) **mysql** runs in a different container I am running **Docker Compose** (https://gist.github.com/f64b54ba5749cbd1f8299fea7b75a25e) and I can effectively connect with `mysql --host=db --user=root --password= datacite` from the container that has Solr. (2) I am assuming the Query in data-config.xml works because (see point 3) but i just ran it directly on mysql and i do get the content back . (3) On the solr version, yes it is very old, but I have this application running already in **solr4** I am just trying to **Dockerise** it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was not connecting to mysql database. **The mysql database host was wrong**. I figure it out thanks to @MatsLindh.

In **docker compose** the name of your `services` is the name of their *host*. So, in my case, the name of the mysql database host is `db` (see docker compose above in the question ). My error was that I had the name of the mysql database host in an environment variable as $DB_HOST = localhost.

I realised when I tried to connect from the solr container to the mysql container. I had to do

```
mysql --host=db --user=root --password= datacite
```

Because

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password= datacite
```

was not working.

So that's it. **Check the database host's names when doing this in docker compose.**